# Granting AnonymousSearchAccessList permission to users in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration, farm-admin

I am trying to grant [AnonymousSearchAccessList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee536458(v=office.15)) permission to a user in SharePoint on-premises.

When I go to Site Permissions and create a new permission level, this does not show up in the list of permissions available

Do we need to enable Anonymous Authentication in the web application level to start seeing this permission level?

Answer (score 1):

The "**AnonymousSearchAccessList**" permission cannot be displayed in the list of available permissions, which requires additional configuration by the administrator.

**Please following steps:**

**StepA: Enable anonymous access at the web application level**

- a1.Go to SharePoint 2013 Central Administration as an admin >> **Application Management** >> **Manage web applications**

[image]

- a2.On the Web Application List page, choose the URL of web application what you wanted and click "**Authentication Providers**". Then, select **Default** Zone.

[image]

- a3.On the "**Edit Authentication**" windows, select "**Enable anonymous access**" option.

[image]

**StepB: Enable anonymous access at the site collection level**

- b1.Go to the site collection as a site admin
- b2.On the Site Settings page, click "**Site permissions**"

[image]

- b3.On the Site Permissions page, click "**Anonymous Access**".

[image]

- b4.On the "Anonymous Access" windows, select "**Entire Web sit**e" or "**Lists or libraries**" option

[image]

**StepC: Enable the below features at the Site Collection Features**

- Cross-Site Collection Publishing
- Limited-access user permission lockdown mode

[image]

**StepD: Set Catalog Settings**

- d1.Go to the list as a site admin
- d2.On the List Settings page, click "**Catalog Settings**"

[image]

- d3.On the Catalog Settings page, click "**Enable anonymous access**" and then select "**Make Anonymous**".

[image]

**StepE: Re-start Full Crawl**

- e1.Go to SharePoint 2013 Central Administration as an admin
- e2.On the Serach Service Application page, click "**Content Sources**". Then, select content source and run "**Start Full Crawl**"

[image]

**Here is my test:**

[image]